# Fetch the matching records from the same table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Id      Name            Group   Role
=====================================
1   ADMIN_GROUP        2    501
1   ADMIN_GROUP        2    502
1   ADMIN_GROUP        2    503
1   ADMIN_GROUP        2    504
1   ADMIN_GROUP        2    1001

3   OtherGroup         2    501
3   OtherGroup         2    502
3   OtherGroup         2    503
3   OtherGroup         2    1001
```

I want to fetch the records according to the role. As per above table the Admin Group contains the
`501,502,503,504,1001` Roles and the OtherGroup contains `501,502,503,1001` Role.

In case of the OtherGroup user selection, I want to fetch the records from AdminGroup also because the admin group contains all the rights which the OtherGroup have. But in case of AdminGroup selection dont fetch the records from the Other Group as the Role 504 is not present for the Other Group

I try the following query

```
   SELECT  DISTINCT Id,Name FROM Tab1  WHERE 1=1   
   AND Role IN (Select Role from Tab1  where Id = 3)
```

Due to the In query sql returns the records from AdminGroup which i dont wants

Comment: Your query, for me, doesn't return anything: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NOJ1jeIK). I would expect this, as none of your rows have a value other than `3` or `1` for `Id`, and you explicitly filter both of those out. Are you not giving us all the relevent sample data?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the sample query. Please check

Comment: Yes, in my original data there are more rows. For simplicity, I have provided the records only for the 2 Ids

Comment: Please include desired results for the given sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with a self join. Below uses the HAVING statement to say "When and only when every role has a match with id = 3, then return the result." If every role has a match it returns 0, otherwise 1, filters for a MAX of 0.

```
SELECT a.Id,a.Name
FROM tbl AS a 
LEFT JOIN tbl AS b 
ON a.role = b.role AND b.id = 3
GROUP BY a.Id,a.Name
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN b.role IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```